# Best way for applying Token Based Authentication in already developed WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, access-token

I have WCF based services with hundreds of endpoints. These services are not secure. I want to add Token Based Authentication on all end points. Issue is that they are too many of them. so, its hard apply check in every function.

```
if(authenticated) 
   Return Response
else 
   Return UnAuthorizedError
```

Is there any way i can use to get it done with minimal code changes. Something like **ActionFilterAttribute**, **IAuthenticationFilter** in MVC.

I have searched for it. But could't find this specific scenario. As there are too many endpoints to change.

Comment: Like ASP.Net, WCF has many extensibility points. You probably want to implement a MessageInspector behavior that you can apply via configuration. I don't remember how well enough to write an answer but that should narrow your research.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement your own `MessageInspector`. Please look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605140/wcf-how-to-pass-token-for-authentication) to have inspiration of how to do that on both client and server side.